# How do I find all the files that were created today in specific folder using Python

Tags: python, time, operating-system

How do I find all the files that were created from 7AM to 7PM from folder and take it as a list in Python

Answer (score 1):

The following code works by storing the current date in a variable(today) and looking for all files inside the directory that have their 'createdAt' timestamp matching that of today's value.

```
import os
import datetime as dt

today = dt.datetime.now().date()
dir = "C:/Dev"  #path to directory

for file in os.listdir(dir):
    filetime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            os.path.getctime(dir + file))   
    if filetime.date() == today:
        print(file)
```

Comment: Thanks man, what should I do If I need files from 7AM to 7PM?